# Auto Increment of one field if primary key of 2 tables are same in 3rd table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

### Tables:

```
Film: in which Id is a primary key, and also the column `number_of_views`

User: in which Id is a primary key

FilmUser: in which I have both the above tables primary keys as a foreign key
```

As users watch the movie, I want to increment `number_of_views`.

How to write this sql query

Comment: The usual way is using the keyboard, although I'm sure other input devices work.

Comment: The condition is that the user has the same database Id as the film? This is how I get it but it makes not much sense.

Comment: I need to use that line sometime @mjh. Original

Comment: In Film table, each film name has some id which is primary key. In User table, each username has some id which is its primary key..  In table FilmUser, if the film name and user name matches more than one time then the Number of view is auto incremented.

Comment: I am going to take the liberty to re-word this question.

Comment: ok how about `update film set number_of_views=number_of_views+1 where pk_id=nnnn`  ... Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is to figure out nnnn.

Comment: so that is as you go along, assuming things are fine and counts exist. If what you are asking is, `hey, I already have data, just added some columns, how do I patch my count data?`, well that is different. Let us know :>